# Set column value based on column values for each row in a table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I would like to search for a particular column value for each row in a table.  The values can be "A", "B", or null.  If the value "A" is found in any of the rows, I would like to assign that value to a column.  If that value does not exist, I would like display the existing column value.

This is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Table

```
record_id     Event_Type
1                A
1                B
1                null
2                B
2                null
3                B
3                A
```

Trying to return the results below

```
record id      Event_Type
1                A
2                B
3                A
```

Answer (score 1):

Via [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/699f7/4/0):

```
create table t1 (record_id number, event_type char(1));

insert into t1 values (1, 'A');
insert into t1 values (1, 'B');
insert into t1 values (1, NULL);
insert into t1 values (2, 'B');
insert into t1 values (2, NULL);
insert into t1 values (3, 'A');
insert into t1 values (3, 'B');

SELECT DISTINCT RECORD_ID, 
       MIN(EVENT_TYPE) OVER (PARTITION BY RECORD_ID ORDER BY EVENT_TYPE NULLS LAST) as event_type
  FROM T1
 ORDER BY RECORD_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you can do what you want with `min()`:

```
select recordid, min(Event_Type) as Event_Type
from table t
group by recordid;
```

But, this is more of a coincidence.  Here is a method that works even when `A` is not alphabetically first:

```
select recordid,
       (case when sum(case when Event_Type = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'A'
             else max(Event_Type)
        end) as Event_Type
from table t
group by recordid;
```